# MacOS: A shortcut to bypass "duplicate file" warning?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, drag-and-drop

When moving files between directories, and a file of the same name already resides in a directory, the MacOS presents the Duplicate file warning asking if you want to `Keep Both`, `Stop`, or `Replace`.

[image]

If I'm dragging/dropping a file and I **know** that if there happens to be a duplicate in the directory I want to replace it in every instance . . .

**Is there some modifier or key combo I can depress when dropping to force replacement?** Bypassing the duplicate warning, thus not having the window focus shift to the copy popup.

Note: I'm aware that depressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key will change the `Keep Both` button to a `Skip` button (or vice versa). I was hoping there may be more modifiers I am unaware of.